# MAMP localhost on vagrant machine

Tags: php, curl, vagrant

I have to get the response from an external API on a Vagrant machine. The API url is:

```
http://local.foobar.vhost/controller/action/
```

Typing the URL on the host machine, with MAMP turned on and vhosts set properly, I get the proper response:

```
{"response": "success", "message": "not set"}
```

And the same goes for the cURL command:

```
curl 'http://local.foobar.vhost/controller/action/'
```

I get the same response here, so everything is ok.

But then I open vagrant with the `vagrant ssh` command, try to get the same response using curl command, and I get the following error:

Couldn't resolve host local.foobar.vhost

I also tried to add the port that MAMP uses, which is 80, so:

```
curl 'http://local.foobar.vhost:80/controller/action/'
```

But it gives me the same error.

How can I make this work?

Thanks!